# Getting a remote page source every 30 min

Tags: php, html

what i want to achieve is: 
1-to get the html source code of remote page eg:http://www.site1.com/page1.html i want ti get the source code of this page every 30 min as this page update content every 30 min .

2-edit this source code somehow then post echo it to my site

i want this all done automatically every 30 min

is it possible to do with php and html

what i have tried untill now:

1- ifram method but i echo the remote page content and i dont have control over it

2- get file content but also cant edit the code before posting it

3- fopen but also cant edit the code before posting it

Comment: Possibly a cron for automated processes?

Comment: why every 30 minutes and no on request?

Comment: Your answer: Yes it is possible to do with php and html. Now what is your question?     @Dagon, he also needs to store the edited result (otherwise it would not work), so this automatically leads to a nice archive with 30 min intervals. Other than that, Daryl Gill is right: simply use a cron-job that runs the php every 30 mins.

Answer (score 0):

To edit the file content, you can use the following code :

```
<?php
$homepage = file_get_contents('http://www.site1.com/page1.html');
// manipulate the $homepage variable
echo $homepage;
?>
```

In order to call this every 30 minutes, you will need some kind of scheduler. The most common way to do this would be to use "Cron jobs", assuming that your hosting provider allows you to use them.

Hope this helps !